# iOS7 Custom Button Fading with UIActionSheet

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, ios7, uiactionsheet

I'm running into an issue where for navigation, we have to use a custom back button, which we are matching to iOS7. So we're creating a UIButton with a background image and then setting it as a custom view of a UIBarButtonItem.

The issue is that when an Action sheet is presented by iOS7, the background is faded. However, the custom button does not and it looks mismatched. Question is - is there a property that can be set to provide the image for the faded state? (though this can be done with delegation, I wanted to see if there was a simpler solution before going that route).

I have tried to set a faded image for UIControlStateDisabled, UIControlStateSystem, UIControlStateReserved with no avail.

Screen shot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually resolved this issue without delegation. The solution is to have a png with clear background. So just the blue of the back arrow. In that case, iOS handles the fading and desaturating. If you add background, it will not.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using delegation. When the action sheet is presented, my controller received a message and switched the button to faded. When action sheet was dismissed, my controller again received a messaged and switched button to normal.

Actionsheet was subclassed here, which is why I had to do this dance.